# Como alinhar um mosaico com CSS?

Tags: html, css

Tenho o seguinte código:

```css
.exemplo {
  width: 800px;
}
img {
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.home-videos {
   /*@extend .col-md-3;*/
   width: 200px;
   height: 150px;
   padding: 5px !important;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   margin: 0px;
   float:left;
}
.home-videos:nth-child(2), .home-videos:last-child{
   /*@extend .col-md-6;*/
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
 }
.home-videos:last-child{
    height: 150px;
 }
 .videos-descript {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
 }
```

```html
<div class="exemplo">
  <figure class="home-videos">
    <img src="http://qnimate.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/images2.jpg">

    <figcaption class="videos-descript">
      <p>Titulo</p>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure class="home-videos">
    <img src="http://qnimate.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/images2.jpg">

    <figcaption class="videos-descript">
      <p>Titulo</p>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure class="home-videos">
    <img src="http://qnimate.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/images2.jpg">

    <figcaption class="videos-descript">
      <p>Titulo</p>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure class="home-videos">
    <img src="http://qnimate.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/images2.jpg">

    <figcaption class="videos-descript">
      <p>Titulo</p>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure class="home-videos">
    <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/758084549821730820/_HYHtD8F.jpg">

    <figcaption class="videos-descript">
      <p>Titulo</p>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure class="home-videos">
    <img src="http://qnimate.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/images2.jpg">

    <figcaption class="videos-descript">
      <p>Titulo</p>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure class="home-videos">
    <img src="http://qnimate.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/images2.jpg">

    <figcaption class="videos-descript">
      <p>Titulo</p>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure class="home-videos">
    <img src="http://qnimate.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/images2.jpg">

    <figcaption class="videos-descript">
      <p>Titulo</p>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
 </div>
```

Gostaria que o "figure" que esta fora de alinhamento, subisse para baixo da primeira imagem, alinhando.

Obs.: Cada 'figure' é um post do Wordpress, por isso não tem outras divs para moldar o mosaico.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sugiro você trabalhar com **[grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)** neste caso. Com este estilo do CSS se torna mais fácil montar mosaicos e alinhamentos como o que deseja, por exemplo.

No seu CSS, adicionei estilos `grid` e alinhei os elementos conforme indicado na pergunta, tratando algumas `<figure>` de forma individual (a 2ª, a 5ª e a última, por terem dimensões e/ou posicionamentos peculiares):

```css
.exemplo {
   width: 800px;
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr); 
   grid-gap: 0px; 
   background-color: #fff; 
   color: #444; 
}
img {
   width:100%;
   height: 100%;
}
.home-videos {
   /*@extend .col-md-3;*/
   width: 200px;
   height: 150px;
   padding: 5px !important;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   margin: 0px;
   float:left;
}
.home-videos:nth-child(2){
   /*@extend .col-md-6;*/
   width: 400px;
   height: 300px;
   
   grid-column: 2 / 3;
   grid-column-end:span 2;
   grid-row: 1 / 2;
   grid-row-end:span 2;
}

.home-videos:nth-child(5){
   grid-row-start: 2;
   grid-column: 1;
}

.home-videos:last-child{
   width: 400px;
   height: 150px;
   /*@extend .col-md-6;*/
   
   grid-column: 3 / 4;
   grid-column-end:span 2;
}
.videos-descript {
   position: absolute;
   display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="exemplo">
  <figure class="home-videos">
    <img src="http://qnimate.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/images2.jpg">

    <figcaption class="videos-descript">
      <p>Titulo</p>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure class="home-videos">
    <img src="http://qnimate.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/images2.jpg">

    <figcaption class="videos-descript">
      <p>Titulo</p>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure class="home-videos">
    <img src="http://qnimate.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/images2.jpg">

    <figcaption class="videos-descript">
      <p>Titulo</p>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure class="home-videos">
    <img src="http://qnimate.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/images2.jpg">

    <figcaption class="videos-descript">
      <p>Titulo</p>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>

  <figure class="home-videos">
    <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/758084549821730820/_HYHtD8F.jpg">

    <figcaption class="videos-descript">
      <p>Titulo</p>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>

  <figure class="home-videos">
    <img src="http://qnimate.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/images2.jpg">

    <figcaption class="videos-descript">
      <p>Titulo</p>
    </figcaption>

  </figure>
  <figure class="home-videos">
    <img src="http://qnimate.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/images2.jpg">

    <figcaption class="videos-descript">
      <p>Titulo</p>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure class="home-videos">
    <img src="http://qnimate.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/images2.jpg">

    <figcaption class="videos-descript">
      <p>Titulo</p>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
 </div>
```

#### Hack para MSIE 9+ e Edge:

Adicione este JS no `<head>`:

```
<script>
var doc = document.documentElement;
doc.setAttribute('data-useragent', navigator.userAgent);
</script>
```

E esse CSS no final do `style` ou do arquivo `.css` externo:

```
html[data-useragent*='rv:11.0'] .home-videos:nth-child(5),
html[data-useragent*='Edge'] .home-videos:nth-child(5),
html[data-useragent*='MSIE 10.0'] .home-videos:nth-child(5),
html[data-useragent*='MSIE 9.0'] .home-videos:nth-child(5){
  position: absolute;
  top: 158px;
  left: 8px;
}
```

Comment: Só uma pergunta, tinha pensado em usar grid, mais quando fui estudar, li que não funciona ainda em todos os navegadores, isso é certo?

Comment: @VictorPereira Só não funciona no IE (Edge). Neste caso teria que fazer um hack. Vou fazer aqui e posto na resposta ok?

Comment: OK, muito obrigado, so uma coisa, a imagem cumprida 'last-child' ela esta no meio, teria como colocar no final?

Comment: @VictorPereira Modifiquei o código conforme seu último comentário, e fiz pequenos melhoramentos no código. Vou ver o lance do hack e aviso.

Comment: @VictorPereira Adicionei no final da resposta um hack para IE.

Answer (score 0):

**Primeira possível solução**

Bom, no quadrado preto, provavelmente eu abusaria um pouco dos margin, se estiver tratando com float, ou dos positions, se estiver tratando com position.

Provavelmente eu tentaria utilizar valor negativo ao TOP, jogando pro local que eu quero o quadrado preto...

Depois, basta dar F12, ou ir redimensionando a tela e vendo quais pixels (width) faz com que talvez a posição negativa do objeto faça ele subir mais ainda; Nesses pixeis (bugs kkk), ajuste com @media e tenha o resultado que você quer.

**Segunda possível solução**

Eu também arriscaria dividir esses grupos de conteúdos em 3 divs, aplicando um

```
width:33.3%;
```

; E moldando da forma desejada

**TERCEIRA E MAIS PROVÁVEL SOLUÇÃO**

Usaria a propriedade COLUMN-COUNT disponibilizada no css3, onde tem-se a possibilidade de criar o conteúdo organicamente; O vídeo abaixo mostra certinho como que monta o estilo dessa forma

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jqx_gANtNhg